# convert function for use with qsort

Tags: c

I'm working on a simple library which operate on vectors.
It define a type of function that is regularly used:

```
typedef float (*vec_pair_fun) (float x, float y);
```

For ease-of-use reason, I want to create a sorting function that use a `vec_pair_fun` to compare each element of a vector.
At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
static vec_pair_fun sort_function;

// follow improvements suggested by @chux below
static int converted_sort_function(const void* a, const void* b){
    //old code: return (int) qsort_function(*(float*)a,*(float*)b);
    float f = sort_function(*(float*)a,*(float*)b);
    return (f > 0.0f) - (f < 0.0f);
}

void vecx_sort(int x, float v[], vec_pair_fun func){
    sort_function=func;
    qsort(v,x,sizeof(float),converted_sort_function);
}
```

but I don't really like that workaround because it's not threadsafe as `sort_function` can be changed by another thread.

Any idea on how to improve this?

---

EDIT: 
One way would be to sort the array myself.
Recoding qsort is really not what I planned to do, so I'm really open for suggestions

Comment: *as sort_function can be changed by another thread.* can you elaborate on that? Why not use a pure function?

Comment: 'sort function' is a global variable. If another thread use 'vecx_sort' while it is already running in the main thread, that program is gonna fail.

Comment: And why is that, if you don't mind asking?

Comment: This design is horrid, but if you're absolutely set on doing this, store the function address you want to invoke in TLS.

Comment: I don't want to do this absolutely... I want my program to be as good as possible. I'm just searching for better ideas, because I really don't like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [wikibooks 5th C implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Quicksort#C) and [Apple's implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c) of a quicksort algorithm, I was able to create my function.
It appear to be quicker than the stdlib version, and it has no global/static variable.

```
// x: length of v
// v: array of float
// func: a function that takes two float as argument and return a float
void vecx_qsort(unsigned int x, float v[], vec_pair_fun cmpf)
{
    float pivot,tmp;
    unsigned int al,l,r,ar,cnt;

    while (x>8)
    {
        cnt=0;

        al=l=1; r=ar=x-1;

        pivot=v[x/2];
        v[x/2]=v[0];
        v[0]=pivot;

        while (1)
        {
            while ( l<=r && (tmp=cmpf(v[l],pivot))<=0.0f ) {
                if(tmp==0.0f){
                    cnt=1;
                    vecx_swap(1,v+al,v+l); //swap vl & val
                    al++;
                }
                l++;
            }
            while ( l<=r && (tmp=cmpf(v[r],pivot))>=0.0f ) {
                if(tmp==0.0f){
                    cnt=1;
                    vecx_swap(1,v+r,v+ar);//swap vr & var
                    ar--;
                }
                r--;
            }

            if(l>r)
                break;
            cnt=1;
            vecx_swap(1,v+r,v+l);

            l++; r--;
        }

        if(cnt==0 && x<=32) // no swap made => almost sorted small array => insertion sort
            break;

        // swap values equal to pivot to the center
        cnt = (al<(l-al))?al:l-al;
        vecx_swap(cnt,v,v+l-cnt); // swap of element before al

        cnt = ((ar-r)<(x-ar-1))?ar-r:x-ar-1;
        vecx_swap(cnt,v+l,v+x-cnt); // swap of element after ar

        l=l-al;  // size of "smaller element array"
        r=ar-r;  // size of "bigger element array"

        // Recursion on the shorter side & loop (with new indexes) on the longer
        if (l>r) {
            vecx_qsort(r, v+x-r, cmpf);
            x=l;
        }
        else {
            vecx_qsort(l, v, cmpf);
            v+=x-r;
            x=r;
        }
    }

    // insertion sort
    for (r=1; r<x; r++)
    {
        pivot=v[r];
        for(l=r; l>0 && cmpf(pivot,v[l-1])<0.0f; l--)
            v[l]=v[l-1];
        v[l]=pivot;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Any idea on how to improve this?
A: Do not cast `float` result to `int` for compare.

Maybe not OP's main concern but `(int) sort_function(*(float*)a,*(float*)b);` is weak.
The FP point result could be `-0.4` or `0.4`, both of these convert to `(int) 0`.
The FP point result could be `> INT_MAX`and conversion to `int` is UB.
Suggest:

```
static int converted_sort_function(const void* a, const void* b){
    float f = sort_function(*(float*)a,*(float*)b);
    return (f > 0.0f) - (f < 0.0f);
}
```

As to your thread safe  problem, consider `qsort_s()` which passes in a context pointer.  `qsort_s()` is specified in C11 Annex K, so it may not exist in your compiler.

```
errno_t qsort_s(void *base, rsize_t nmemb, rsize_t size,
    int (*compar)(const void *x, const void *y, void *context), 
    void *context);
```

Comment: Thank, I added your improvement to `converted_sort_function` to my post.

As for the qsort_s/qsort_r function, it just introduce a new level of complication that I don't want to add.

Comment: @yakoudbz  1) Using `qsort_s()` is a unwanted complication 2) using a static variable `sort_function` is not liked because it is not  thread safe and 3) recoding `qsort()` is not planned.  We are running out of options.  IMO #1 is not complicated and ultimately the best approach.

Comment: ok :), I thought there was maybe another way... 
qsort_s/qsort_r are extensions, and if I allow extensions, I could even de a gcc nested function inside `vecx_sort` which is a solution too. I think there are plenty other solutions like this.
I even prefer to recode a quicksort algorithm myself than to use qsort_s :p